# Saving downloaded data as well as trained model

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, execution

Is there a way to save the execution of a particular block of code in a notebook such that I don't have to run it again. And can continue with the rest of code after reloading? 
For example,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

(train_images1, train_labels), (test_images1, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images1 / 255.0, test_images1 / 255.0

#My cnn model, upto the training
#Save upto here.
```

Can I save the execution upto here for later usage, that is including the **downloaded files** and **trained model**.

Comment: What is actually looking  you? Save train and test data to NumPy array or in H5 file? Or something else? It isn't possible Save execution of a notebook, rather you can save downloaded data.

Comment: @ashraful Save the executed data so that I don't have to start from scratch again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Save Model:**

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model .......")
```

**Load saved Model:**

```
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model...........")
```

For more details, You can find my implementation [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14LvGLyfTFDKjkYcYvF_3u80g5MEYEbla?usp=sharing). Now this will save both `dataset as well as trained model` also.

Comment: Can this store trained models?

Comment: I was looking for saving the trained model, not the databases.

Answer (score 1):

There is! You can save your NumPy data using `numpy.save("train_images.npy", train_images)` and load them using `train_images = numpy.load("train_images.npy")`. When working with notebooks, just put `save` and `load` in two different cells and run whatever cell you need.

Documentation:

- [`save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html?highlight=save#numpy.save)
- [`load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load)

There are many variations like `savez` to save multiple arrays in an uncompressed file or `savez_compressed` for compressed files.

Comment: Can you verify that it does work? I had no idea whether you have actually used NumPy arrays. If you use NumPy arrays, this is the de-facto standard way to do it.

Comment: But I would also like to have my deep learning trained model saved too.

Comment: This can easily be done using https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Comment: Can you please post it in the answer, that it may be helpful to someone else also? And I shall accept this.